# Reading a non-null terminated input at serial?

Tags: mbed

I am working with mbed, the LPC1768. The serial input to the mbed is a unsigned character array which is not null-terminated. I don't get anything with getc(), how to get the input?

Comment: `getc` should work fine, as you read one character at the same time. Are you sure the UART works? If you set a `sigio` callback does it fire?

Answer (score 0):

**the null character is 0 so if you need get it u can using a Buffer Counter or a ovf variable to detect received a character!!**
Config your UART0,1 by this Setting:
comment UART0 or UART1 if not use it!

### so u can select UARTs with #define in: option->C/C++->Define:__UART0 or __UART1

```
void SER_Init (void) {
#ifdef __UART0                             /* UART0 */
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= ((1 << 3) | (1 << 15)); /* enable power to UART0 & IOCON   */

  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |=  (1 << 4);        /* Pin P0.2 used as TXD0           */
  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |=  (1 << 6);        /* Pin P0.3 used as RXD0           */
#else                                      /* UART1 */
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= ((1 << 4) | (1 << 15)); /* enable power to UART1 & IOCON   */

  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 |=  (2 << 0);        /* Pin P2.0 used as TXD1           */
  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 |=  (2 << 2);        /* Pin P2.1 used as RXD1           */
#endif

  UART->LCR    = 0x83;                     /* 8 bits, no Parity, 1 Stop bit   */
  UART->DLL    = 9;                        /* 115200 Baud Rate @ 25.0 MHZ PCLK*/
  UART->FDR    = 0x21;                     /* FR 1,507, DIVADDVAL=1, MULVAL=2 */
  UART->DLM    = 0;                        /* High divisor latch = 0          */
  UART->LCR    = 0x03;                     /* DLAB = 0                        */
}
```

------> and use this func. for Get Character:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Read character from Serial Port   (blocking read)
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int SER_GetChar (void) {

  while (!(UART0->LSR & 0x01));
  return (UART0->RBR);
}
```